# He loves cooking, doesn't he? OR He love cooking, doesn't he?

Tags: grammar

He loves cooking, doesn't he? OR He love cooking, doesn't he? Do we need "s" at the end of "love" if we are using "does not"?

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question! Unlike the regular question format where the "s" is dropped when the tense is third-person singular (e.g."Does he *love* cooking?"). Affirmative and negative tag questions follow the same rules as if you were making a statement (e.g "He *loves* cooking, doesn't he?" "He doesn't like cooking, does he?").

Answer (score -3):

It is "he loves cooking, doesn't he?", not the other. The 'doesn't' indicates a present verb tense, which means that the form of 'to love' is loves.

Comment: Yep. "Loves" agrees with "doesn't", whereas "love" would agree with "don't", as in "I love cooking, don't I?"

Comment: @wonkypiano -  I think you're confused. love(s) agrees with He/I. It has nothing to do with doesn't/don't.   He loves cooking. I love cooking. Doesn't/Don't also agrees with He/I:  I do. He does.

Comment: The sentence tag is supposed to follow the subject/verb of the independent clause, not vice versa. -1